# Splitting lines at multiple points in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, distance, splitting

I have two shapefiles:

1. First shapefile consists of lines features (approx 1500); it represents the public transport lines
2. Second shapefile consists of point features (approx 3000); it represents the public transport stops on the lines

Now, I want to do a analysis on it and I want to split each line feature into half according to the points. For example I have one line with starting point A and ending point B and 3 point features (lets say a,b,c) on it. I want to split the line and calculate the distance as follows:

1. Split the line in two parts one is from A-a and a-B
2. Split the same line two part one is from A-b and b-B
3. Split the same line two part one is from A-c and c-B

This is what I want to do for the entire network but doing it manually will take a lot of time. How can I  identify the tool which can do it fast and without any error?

Comment: So from single line with 3 stops you'd like produce 6 overlapping  segments or it is 4  of them without overlap?

Comment: Yes 6 overlapping segments

Comment: If you want to use model builder then use a feature iterator feeding points into the [split tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/tools/data-management-toolbox/split-line-at-point.htm) and then embed that model into a model iterating over your lines. I suspect you will get better performance and control over looping if you write this in python.

Answer (score 1):

There's a tool called [Split Lines at Point](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/split-line-at-point.htm) in ArcGIS, maybe you can work it out from there.